# Dynamically Calculate Pace in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calculator, dynamically-generated

I have this code below. How would dynamically calculate the pace as I fill in the fields instead of having to calculate it manually by tapping on the Calculate Pace button?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var minTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var distTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var paceLabel: UILabel!


    func paceInSeconds (minutes:Double, seconds: Double, distance: Double) -> Double {
        return ((minutes*60) + seconds) / distance
    }


    @IBAction func paceCalculator(sender: UIButton) {
        var paceMinutes = paceInSeconds(((minTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue, seconds: (secTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue, distance: (distTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue)) / 60

        var roundedPaceMinutes = Double(floor(paceMinutes))
        var decimalPaceSeconds = paceMinutes - roundedPaceMinutes
        var intPaceMinutes = Int(floor(roundedPaceMinutes))
        var paceSeconds = Int(floor(decimalPaceSeconds * 60))
        var paceSecondsZero = String(format: "%02d", paceSeconds)

        paceLabel.text = "\(intPaceMinutes):\(paceSecondsZero)/km"
    }    
}
```

Here's the storyboard UI:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the various functions of the [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/) protocol. If you assign your view controller as the *delegate* of the text field, it will be able to act upon changes in the text field.

In your case, you should implement the [`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) function.

Comment: I'm quite a beginner to programming, so this doesnt make much sense. I'm busy reading more about the above to make more sense of it.

Am I right if I do this for the UITextFieldDelegate:
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate 

Also, Im busy figuring out how to implement the function, but will revert if I get completely lost.)